# Best way to track users for analytics? - Mobile

Tags: php, web, analytics, bigdata, database

This is more of a conceptual question than a specific code question.

Right I am developing a mobile app and am trying to figure out the best way to track data.  What I mean by this is:

For every user that signs up I want them to have custom analytics for their accounts based off of the users interactions with them.

For example if it was Facebook:
We have 3 user profiles (a,b,c)
I need to know every time a user visits profile A (basic count)
I need to know every time a user visits profile B (basic count)
I need to know every time a user visits profile C (basic count)

I then need to return these values via reports to users A,B,C about their accounts.

I was thinking of keeping a tracking structure in my SQL database then generating reports from that.  Is this the best way to do it or are there other ways of tracking/storing/reporting data for mobile applications?  I was looking into google analytics and stuff but how would I get reports specific to their accounts (filters) then manipulate that data so I can repost it through my website portal for them to log into their account to see?

Comment: Note to self, read whole question. I'd suggest using Google Analytics, the API might give you some insight as to being able to get the graphs etc.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. How to do design your system is way too broad and basically asks for opinions, which are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Yes, this is not a good question for this community. As for my opinion: Only collect user data if this is essential to your app, and for your user. For instance, I don't use Office 365 specifically because they track my usage of the software, and show this when I log in. Why do they do this?